# Add files to zip with php

Tags: php, download, zip

my php code for create zip file is:

```
function zipFilesDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }

    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
      if (!file_exists($files)) { die($files.' does not exist'); }
      if (!is_readable($files)) { die($files.' not readable'); }
        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$archive_file_name"); 
    exit;
}
if ($act=="backup") {
$fileNames=array('us/man.txt');
$zip_file_name='myFile.zip';
$file_path=dirname(__FILE__).'/';
zipFilesDownload($fileNames,$zip_file_name,$file_path);
}
```

i add this code in my php, page show this code instead download:

```
PK0�~E1x��us/man.txtKIPK0�~E1x��users/mohammad-ali/mamad.txtPKJ>
```

but if i add it in another php, zip file downloaded correctly.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting the real problem. Let's see: The same code works somewhere and doesn't works somewhere else? If it's so, show us this "somewhere", and the "somewhere else". The difference will be there, not in this code.

Comment: it's work but in "somewhere else" ZIP file is read that makes garbage text instead of downloading!

Comment: But the code is the same in both cases, aren't they? If it is, the problem is: a) Some other code diferent in "somewhere" than in "somewhere else". (Same code should always do the same thing.) b) The places where "somewhere" and "somewhere else" are located. (You are using relative locations, so maybe the problem is there). Another question: Does your server show "notices"/"warnings"? Maybe a hidden notice has the key to your problem.